# Edit piecewise function

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

Downstream of a long process I got the following function:

$\begin{cases} 0 & x < 0 \, \vee \, x > \frac{307}{400} \\
14.27-7.44\,x & 0 < x < \frac{307}{400} \\
\text{Indeterminate} & \text{True} \end{cases}$

I would like to know if you can delete the last case, without manual intervention, but with a code. I searched far and wide but could not find anything effective.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe just do `expr /. Intermediate -> 0`? (Where `expr` is your function.)

Comment: @march `/. Indeterminate -> 0` But yes, this works.

Comment: @Feyre. I can't even blame autocorrect because I typed that on my computer.  :)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a good application for [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html):

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {0, x < 0}, {Indeterminate, True}}]
f[x]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  1 & x>0 \\
>  0 & x<0 \\
>  \text{Indeterminate} & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$$

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{f[x], x != 0}, {0, True}}]
h[x_] = PiecewiseExpand[g[x]]
```

> $$\begin{cases}
>  1 & x>0 \\
>  0 & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$$

I split this up into steps just for illustration. The end result is the function `h` which has only the two relevant cases.